# How to give increment without autoincrement for id in table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have table like test.There are fields like id,name.I don't want to give auto increment to id.So how will i give increment to id ? 
I can fetch max(id) from table and +1 to that number and can assign that id.
But problem is that there are 1000 of records are inserting in a second so how can i overcome this problem ? 
Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Why don't you want an auto-increment? You describe the quintessential usecase for AI, and then go on to find ways to do it differently. Your fetch-and-assign will most likely cause problem with concurrency as you somewhat tried to point out. Please clarify your actual use-case

Comment: @Nanne  Auto increment is not allowed for my table.It's client's requirements.

Comment: That's ... odd.. there must be a reason for this. Without the reason it's hart to recreate the functionality because we don't know what part offends the client.

Answer (score 0):

create a second table e.g. `id_generator` with field `id`(as id), `table_name`(string) and `value`(integer). `table_name` contains the name of the tabe you use the value for, in your case it is `test`. `value` stores the current maximum value of your id column in your `test` table + 1. e.g. if the maximum id in talbe test is 1000 the value in id_generator is 1001.
Whenever you insert a new value into your `test` table you fetch the value from `id_genrator` use it as the id for the insert into `test`, increment the value and store it back to the `id_generator` table.

In this way you implement your own "autoincrement" for ids. With one additional table you speed up the fetching as you store the current max id seperated.

Comment: WHy would you need a separate table for this? It's not like fetching a value is much quicker then fetching the max value of an indexed row?